# WPF Databinding for ContextMenu and TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a problem with my small WPF tray icon which has a context menu assigned. If I do a right-click on the tray icon the context menu opens and you see a text box containing an integer value. Now when clicking to the "Create Instance" field the integer should increment by one. The new value should be shown in the textbox. On startup the correct inital value is shown in the textbox but changes during runtime are not reflected to the UI. I think there is a data binding problem... The click event is caught and even the value is incremented but the textbox does not recognize the new value...

I have no Main Window the application should only be a tray icon context menu.

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    // This objects are global
    private TaskbarIcon notifyIcon;
    private INotificationBarMessage message = null;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        //create the notifyicon (a resource declared in NotifyIconResources.xaml)
        notifyIcon = (TaskbarIcon) FindResource("Key_NotifyIcon");
        notifyIcon.DataContext = this;

        message = new NotificationBarMessage(notifyIcon);
        message.Show(TextType.Startup);
    }
}
```

ResourceContextMenu.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserInterface.ViewModel"
                    x:Class="UserInterface.ViewModel.EventHandlerUI">

<ContextMenu x:Shared="false" x:Key="My_ContextMenu">
    <ContextMenu.DataContext>
        <local:ContextMenuModel /> <!-- reference to ContextMenuModel.cs -->
    </ContextMenu.DataContext>

    <!-- DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}} -->
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
        <local:ConverterBoolToVisibility x:Key="BoolToHiddenConverter"
                                         TrueValue="Visible" 
                                         FalseValue="Hidden" />
        <local:ConverterIntToString x:Key="IntToStringConverter" />
    </ContextMenu.Resources>

    <TextBlock Text="Status"/>

    <Separator/>

    <MenuItem Header="Create Instance"
              MouseEnter="CreateInstance_OverEnter"
              MouseLeave="CreateInstance_OverExit"
              Click="CreateInstance_Click"
              StaysOpenOnClick="True" />
        <!-- Command="{Binding ShowWindowCommand}" -->
    <MenuItem Header="Open Window"
              StaysOpenOnClick="True"
              Command="{Binding Commands.ShowWindowCommand}" />   
    <MenuItem Header="IP-Address"
              Name="MenuItem_IPAddress"
              Visibility="{Binding EventData.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay,
                  Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}"
              StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
    <TextBox Width="100"
             Text="{Binding Path=EventData.Counter,
                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay,
                 Converter={StaticResource IntToStringConverter}}"/>

    <Separator/>

    <MenuItem Header="Exit"
              Command="{Binding Path=Commands.ExitApplicationCommand}" />
</ContextMenu>

<!-- Tray Icon -->
<!-- the application's NotifyIcon - started from App.xaml.cs.
     Declares its own view model. -->
<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="Key_NotifyIcon"
                x:Name="My_NotifyIcon"
                IconSource="/View/gfx/_UserInterface.ico"
                ToolTipText="tip"
                ContextMenu="{StaticResource My_ContextMenu}"/>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="UserInterface.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Note that this application does not have a StartupUri declared,
         so no Window is automatically loaded.
         Also, the ShutdownMode was set to explicit,
         so we have to close the application programmatically. -->

    <!-- merge NotifyIcon and related stuff into the application -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceContextMenu.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Here is the code where I fire the property changed event:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

private int _counter = 34;

public int Counter
{
    get
    {
        return this._counter;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != this._counter)
        {
            this._counter = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the converter plz, and see.

Comment: Where ever you are changing the EventData.Counter property are you calling a property changed event?

Comment: Yes I have added this code above. The problem is that PropertyChanged is NULL so I cannot fire the event.... I don't know why